# Put numbers from 1 to 6 in the puzzle

Tags: logical-deduction, logic-grid

Put the numbers from 1 to 6 in the puzzle in a way such that:

1. In each row or column there shouldn't are no duplicate numbers.
2. The squares that are joined together have the same number.

[image]

Comment: It's not really an original question isn't it?
http://www.puzzlepicnic.com/puzzle?1123

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found one solution and i dont think there is another. The red marked four is the first number you can fill in.

[image]

Comment: This is what I got too.

Comment: The 3 on the right side can also be the first number you can fill in.
Try putting it in the others cells and it will add a 3 in the 4th column or the last row which is invalid.

Comment: @alixeisenhardt , how does one proceed after filling the 4s ?